# How can I correctly change getElementById on getElementByClassName?

Tags: javascript

Help please to understand how to change correctly one existing function:

```
var o=document.getElementById('input-option77');
var mon = o.options[o.selectedIndex].getAttribute('price_value');
var nmon = Number(mon);
```

with getElementByClassName.

I tried it to do it in such a way, but answer is NaN:

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
var nmon = Number(e[0].options[e[0].selectedIndex].price_value);
```

my example form:

```
<select name="test-name" id="input-option77" class="main-form test">
<option value="test1" price_value="0">Select1</option>
<option value="test2" price_value="200">Select2</option>
<option value="test3" price_value="300">Select3</option>
</select>
```

Thank you!

Comment: `price_value` is not a valid attribute, and it's certainly not a property. You could get it with `getAttribute('price_value')`, but you should be using data-attributes instead

Comment: As @adeneo says, the only code you needed to change was to add [0] to getElementsByClassName:  `var o=document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];`

Comment: @adeneo - Thank for you reply. i check your solution - but i have error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Comment: @freedomn-m - Thank for you reply. I try what you say, but i have errors. Could ypu please, check my UPD

Comment: Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v5w0yokm/   are you sure you don't have something else?  Like other elements with class `test`

Comment: @freedomn-m   THANK YOU!! All work now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only code you need to change from `getElementById` to `getElementsByClassName` is to add [0] to `getElementsByClassName`:

```
var o=document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];
```

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array, and, assuming there's only one, you just need the first entry in that array.

Putting back the `.getAttribute` gives you code:

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0]; 
var emon = Number(e.options[e.selectedIndex].getAttribute('price_value'));
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v5w0yokm/

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByClassName returns an Array-like HTMLCollection, so you just need to access the first element on your query

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];
```